# Get url-friendly version of the_title?

Tags: url-rewriting, get-the-title

How can I get an url-friendly version of the post_title? I´m using anchor links for my posts on an archive page, and for the moment the posts get the post_ID as a hash tag but I would like to get the title instead as it would look nicer.

Comment: what code is used to generate these anchor links?

Comment: I just set the ID of my post to the post_ID. Then I can anchor link to them with a link where the href is #post_ID. No funky code or anything...

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function for url encoding that would probably work:

```
urlencode( get_the_title() );
```

Comment: Probably had better do:
`urlencode( get_the_title( $post->ID ) );`

Comment: @pippin's right assuming you're outside of the loop.

Comment: `urlencode( get_the_title() );` gives me: S%C3%A4kerheten+f%C3%B6rst for the title "Säkerheten först". Not really good looking. I´m looking for something which gives me: "sakerheten-forst".

Comment: To get that, I think you'll have to write a regex expression. Sadly, I'm terrible at those.

Comment: @Johan why not use the slug then?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the short version with "-" between the words use the slug.
If you don't want to use the slug use the function bellow:

```
<?php
    $new_url = sanitize_title(get_the_title());
    echo $new_url;
?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title